# Change color of sectionIndexTitle when section is selected (UITableView)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableView with sectionIndexTitles and I would like to change the selected section letter color to red.

I could use: `tableView.sectionIndexColor = .darkGray` but this changes the color of all letters. I only want to change the color of the letter currently selected.

Basically, as you swipe your finger through the alphabet, the letter selected should be RED. Only SELECTED letter red and the rest BLUE (or other color)

Also, I would like to increase the height of the alphabet so that top is same as the top of table view and same for the bottom.

Any suggestions comments?

Here is a screenshot of what I have right now:

[image]

**FOR ANYONE INTERESTED IN THE ANSWER**

I ended up implementing this functionality myself. I will be sharing what I did here soon.

:)

Comment: None of what you want to do is supported by the table view API.

Comment: By the way, the index is just a simple list of buttons. You would have to write it by yourself and put it manually over the table. Scrolling to a specific section by clicking one of the buttons is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

> I only want to change the color of the letter currently selected...
>
> I would like to increase the height of the alphabet so that top is same as the top of table view and same for the bottom...

Sounds great, but that is not how the built-in index column feature works, so to accomplish this, you would have somehow to reinvent the entire index column feature from scratch, yourself. If that's really what you want to do, go for it, if you think it's a good use of your time, but my advice would be, keep your desires in line with the features provided by the UIKit framework. *Use* the framework, don't *fight* it.